# What is a good way to represent data in a multilingual dictionary? Wordnet alternatives or extensions?

Tags: cross-linguistic, dictionary

I'm not a linguist so forgive my misuse of terminology... I'm looking for a data structure to represent dictionary entries. A dictionary would have words translated to other languages along with links to other words (synonyms and such), definitions, examples, etc.

Wordnet structure looks pretty good, but I'm trying to compare it to alternatives. How would one combine multiple wordnets in a single dictionary? Perhaps each word within synset must me linked to its translation in another synset rather than linking synsets together.

I would appreciate any suggestions. Are there any real life examples on how other dictionaries do it?

Here is for example how Wordnet looks like in xml (nouns file):

```
<synset id="n04779053" type="n">
<lex_filenum>07</lex_filenum>
<word lex_id="1">agreeableness</word>
<word lex_id="0">amenity</word>
<pointer refs="n04778630">Hypernym</pointer>
<pointer refs="a00089051" source="1" target="1">Derivationally related form</pointer>
<pointer refs="n04779895" source="1" target="1">Antonym</pointer>
<def>pleasantness resulting from agreeable conditions</def>
<example>a well trained staff saw to the agreeableness of our accommodations</example>
<example>he discovered the amenities of reading at an early age</example>
```

source: http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lapalme/WordNet-XML/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Francis Bond](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/fcbond/) has done a lot of work in consolidating resources for multilingual Wordnets. Perhaps you don't have to implement any such dataset yourself; the language-pair you're interested in might already be available [here](http://compling.hss.ntu.edu.sg/omw/).

Answer (score 1):

[OmegaWiki](http://omegawiki.org) is another large-scale, multilingual dictionary reference.

Comment: what makes it different to Wikitionary?

Comment: @Ooker Wiktionary is a set of independent dictionaries, and each of these dictionaries has a specific source language (English Wiktionary, French Wiktionary, etc.). OmegaWiki is a single, multi-lingual dictionary, which makes it more scalable.

Comment: I hope there are more editorial control on OmegaWiki than Wiktionary, because it's full of mistakes. People tends to write their own definition of a word, or to consider a spelling or grammar mistake is not one when a lot of people make it.