# up-to-date french version of WordNet ready to use in ElasticSearch

Tags: wordnet

I'm looking for a decent, up-to-date *french* version of WordNet ready to use in ElasticSearch.
We already found Wolf and WoNeF but the format is not accepted by ElasticSearch.
(We're using ES v2.4)

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6275/what-is-a-good-way-to-represent-data-in-a-multilingual-dictionary-wordnet-alter